# Drupal 6.16 Webforms module permission issue

Tags: php, drupal

I'm running Drupal 6.16 and the Webform module changes all the permissions.

I have to change the node_access values in the mySQL database table to make the pages visible to everyone. This is the same issue as outlined [here](http://drupal.org/node/1358306)

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each webform can have it's own permissions.
Users do NOT need "create webform nodes" permission to submit the form.
Check settings in Administer > Settings > Webform and each webform's settings (/admin/settings/webform settings can be overriden on per-node basis)